# How do I add a polygon into my Google local business map?

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3, google-places-api, google-places

I want to add the same circle on my google place/business listing as in attached image. Please help me out.

Google Local Business Map

[image: Google Local Business Map]

Comment: Features polygons are not available via Google Maps JavaScript API. The corresponding feature request is: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/35816953

Answer (score 0):

You need to use [Google My Business](https://www.google.com/business/) and [define a service area](https://support.google.com/business/answer/3038163?co=GENIE.Platform%3DDesktop&hl=en) for your business. See also [Guidelines for representing your business on Google](https://support.google.com/business/answer/3038177?hl=en) and beware that your business won't be available in the Maps APIs until [this bug](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/35828187) is fixed.